# Integration of (Tsiolkovsky) rocket equation with external forces

Tags: integration, mathematical-astronomy

I am trying to find the distance of a rocket by integrating its velocity equation, that is, the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation. The equation with gravity:

$v(t) = v_{0} + u \ln\frac{m_{0}}{m_{f}} - g t $

where $u$ is the effective exhaust velocity (a constant), $m_{0}$ and $m_{f}$ are the initial and final masses of the rocket, $g$ is gravity, $v_{0}$ is the initial velocity and $t$ is time.

So far I found this [Integration of (Tsiolkovsky) rocket equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144257/integration-of-tsiolkovsky-rocket-equation) and many more like that, which helps me a lot, but does not consider external forces on the object.

I have been trying to do this on my own, but my math skills are not so great and every equation for '$x$' or 'height ' that I got resulted in some negative height, which is not possible.

My question is, what is the integral of the mentioned equation if we assume that $v_{0}$ does't equal zero, and gravity changes according to the following formula:

$$g = G \frac{m}{r^2}$$

where '$m$' is the mass of the earth, and '$r$' is the distance from the core of the earth.  '$r$' is defined as the radius of earth + height of rocket.

Comment: It is a nonlinear ODE once $g$ is nonlinearly coupled to $h$. You should not expect a closed analytical solution.

Comment: yeah I know, I'm using a computer program to map the equation out, I'm just looking for a more simplified expression. @Ian